# Should the wording "Want to start your own Stack Exchange Q&A site?" be changed?

Tags: discussion, design, area-51, wording

From the bottom of [the sites page](https://stackexchange.com/sites):

> [image: Want to start your own Stack Exchange Q&A site? Check out Area 51. Our friendly robots are waiting.]

It feels like *Want to start your own Stack Exchange Q&A site?* is the wrong phrase: people cannot create *their own* Stack Exchange Q&A site through Area 51.  (Although, perhaps they can through [Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams).)

**Question**: Should the wording "Want to start your own Stack Exchange Q&A site?" be changed?

Maybe "Want to propose a Stack Exchange Q&A site?" is a reasonable choice.  Or maybe just delete this sentence entirely.

Comment: Area51 is a dead man walking site.